# whats the best way to have text inside a svg code?

Tags: html, css, svg, perspective

I have a 4 page leaflet (in perspective view) designed with illustrator and exported as SVG .I have some text on each page of the leaflet , its too heavy for web rendering ,(as the text is converted to paths). so I decided to keep the base leaflet as SVG and find a way to simulate perspective in the accompanying text and match it to the leaflets perspective, I also found the scripts to make the perspective happen but as soon as I place (inline)the perspective text in the SVG code it acts in a very different way I've made screenshots of the end result I want to achieve so you can see what I mean.
[desired end result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKvoc.png)

i use **foreignObject** tag to implement html inside svg .

[code i did and whats happening](https://iqstudio.us/temp/leaflet.html)

Comment: How about SVG’s [`<text>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/text) element?

Comment: @MTCoster very difficult to add styles like height or width , or must add each single row of text inside a separated text tag , i tried this before but not a good deal . i think its good to one single row text not a paragraph

Comment: Your live example doesn't make it clear what you want to happen there. Is it that the perspective doesn't fit what you want to achieve? Were you unable to position the text correctly? Is it that the div is cut off? (that one is easily corrected with `overflow:visble` on the foreignObject)

Comment: @ccprog see the page [example](http://www.iqstudio.us/temp/leaflet.html)  inspect the text element , its jump out of parent div , see the parent div is in a correct place of its parent , and when you resize window every thing behave responsive except text, in addition even h2 tag and p tag are on a correct way , but text inside them just jump out there . is not it abnormal ?!

Comment: I would suggest you don't use a foreignObject.  It is not entirely surprising to me that the 3D transform on a `<div>` inside a `<foreignObject>` does not behave correctly.  You are probing the dark boundary of the browser there :).  Why not just pull your `<div>` out of the SVG and just give it the 3D transform to position it over the correct part of the SVG?  You could even put the SVG for one page in the div and then everything on the page would get the correct perspective transform.  For example lines would get smaller towards the back.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau tnx to answer , do you think the <div> that you talk about , behave correct on responsive ? i mean when window be resized the <div> with text inside it would behave right position with svg ? by the way i'll code what you said to see result ;)

Comment: @PaulLeBeau you know , when you resize window svg behaves in its own way because of the viewBox attribute it has , and matching  it with  another div is an issue

Comment: It should be possible: http://jsfiddle.net/qx2a7t5o/

Comment: @PaulLeBeau you see , your example shows the point i was trying to say , there is no relative scaling responsiveness between  the text and svg

Comment: Oh. I see what you mean.  Just use a font size relative to the page width: http://jsfiddle.net/qx2a7t5o/1/

Comment: Is your text really that slow (ie unusably slow) when converted to outlines?

Comment: Assuming it **is** unusably slow, have you tried making each page a standalone SVG embedded as an `<img>`? It should be cached by the browser and should render fast.  If you give it a high resolution, it should still look okay when 3D transformed.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau i thought maybe  taking vw (view width) to font-size works correctly but when i test it , nope . you don't want to text behaves relative with window width , you want to make it behaves with svg's behave

Comment: the issue is this just don't want use image , something like feeling you can select text , copy it or etc , ux you know

Comment: Then just put the text inside the SVG how you like, and 3D transform the SVG. Just have one SVG per page so that each SVG can be transformed independently.  Just make sure that you include the font on the page (ie a webfont) so that every browser has it.

Comment: i think its better and simpler  if i code for every window resolution and use css to position the text . any way tnx for the advise